# Library upgrade issues (1.4 to 1.8)

Tags: java

One of the project works developed in JDK 1.4 and now i am unable to compile in 1.8 version jdk
Is the below errors are due to upgrade or some jars is missing?

```
1. import javax.servlet.http.*; cannot be resolved
2. Base64 is ambiguous
3. HttpServletResponse could not be resolved
4. HttpSession could not be resolved
5. org.w3c.domElement could not be resolved
```

Thanks.

Comment: javax.servlet isn't part of SE, you need to download the EE jdk.

Comment: Errors 3 and 4 happen for the same reason as error 1: you did not include the servlet API in your classpath while compiling (see azurefrog's remark).

Comment: Error 5 looks like a typo: there's `org.w3c.dom.Element` but not `org.w3c.domElement`.

Comment: I am using Ant build.xml to build the project. Can we include the servlet jar alone with JDK or we need to download the EE JDK only? I want to make it light weight

Comment: It depends what you are building.  If this a webapp (WAR file) to be deployed on a web container, then the WAR file doesn't need to contain any Java EE artifacts.  They are typically provided **at runtime** by the web container.  (You just need the APIs at compile time to compile against.)